# What is your favorite Python mocking library?

Tags: python, mocking

What is your single favorite mocking library for Python?

Comment: minimock which uses doctest

Comment: "Mockito is a mocking framework that tastes really good. It lets you write beautiful tests with clean & simple API. Mockito doesn't give you hangover because the tests are very readable and they produce clean verification errors." https://code.google.com/p/mockito/

Answer (score 43):

I've only used one, but I've had good results with Michael Foord's Mock: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/.

Michael's introduction says it better than I could:

> There are already several Python mocking libraries available, so why another one?
>
> Most mocking libraries follow the 'record -> replay' pattern of mocking. I prefer the 'action -> assertion' pattern, which is more readable and intuitive particularly when working with the Python unittest module.
>
> ...
>
> It also provides utility functions / objects to assist with testing, particularly monkey patching.

Comment: mock is now part of the Python standard library, available as unittest.mock in Python 3.3 onwards.

Comment: Do NOT use backported mock with Python 2.x! It is last updated in 2012, riddled with bugs (see the issues on google code!). Stay away.

Answer (score 8):

[Mox](http://code.google.com/p/pymox/), from Google

Comment: I find it poorly documented, in a very non-intuitive way.

Answer (score 5):

[Mocker](http://labix.org/mocker) from Gustavo Niemeyer.

It's not perfect, but it is very powerful and flexible.

Comment: Mocker is extensively covered in Daniel Arbuckle's "Python Testing: Beginner's Guide" (Packt).

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author for mocktest. I think it's pretty fully featured and easy to use, but I might be biased:

http://gfxmonk.net/dist/doc/mocktest/doc/

Answer (score 4):

[Dingus](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dingus/), by Gary Bernhardt.

Answer (score 3):

[pyDoubles](http://www.pydoubles.org) the test doubles framework for Python, by iExpertos.com. It supports mocks, stubs, spies and matchers, including Hamcrest matchers

Comment: The url redirect to a Chinesse site.
https://bitbucket.org/DavidVilla/python-doublex

Answer (score 0):

I've used [pMock](http://pmock.sourceforge.net/) in the past, and didn't mind it, it had pretty decent docs too. However, Foord's Mock as mentioned above is also nice.

Comment: That's what the pMock's author says about pMokc: "_Just to note that pMock is no longer in development (really must update the web page), actually it was more an experiment I finished playing with about four years ago and assumed the "alpha" designation would scare people away._" [http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/002262.html]