# How to create test objects in tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, class-design

I'm creating unittests to a payment process. There is about 20 unit unittests to write -some positives cases and some negatives.

example:

```
payment_screen=PaymentScreen()
```

and there I few conceptions.

First - create a Payer object with giving attributes:

```
payer=Payer(last_name,country_code)
```

country_code is important, because system doesn't allow to sending items to other countries

Second

```
payer=Payer.return_correct_payer()
```

something like:

class Payer:

```
 @staticmethod
 def return_correct_payer():
 payer=Payer()
 payer.country_code='US'
 payer.last_name='Smith'
```

and in both options

```
payment_screen.fill_payer_data(payer)
```

And an another conception:

in payment_screen just create two methods:

```
fill_payer_data_with_correct_data()
```

and

```
fill_payer_data_with_uncorrect_data()
```

Which one is the best? Or maybe you have another idea(I'm sure that you have)

**EDIT**

Thanks for your replies, but it's not what I need. 
I just don't want create object Pax in every test case with giving attributes.

I have 20 test cases so now I must write 20 times :

```
payer=Payer('Smith','US')
```

I don't want duplicate my code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is some kind of mocking framework. Then when you test `PaymentScreen`, you can mock out `Payer`. For more about mocking frameworks for python look here: [What is your favorite Python mocking library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98053/104750).

Answer (score 0):

Hey.
Probably answer with mocks is what you need in the first place, but I want to show how I create objects in my tests. 
So if I need a object with given parameters I use BuilderPattern (actually modified BuilderPattern from GOF), which looks like this:

```
class User  {
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;

    public User(){};

    //now the essence
    public User withFirstName(strFirstName) {
        this.firstName = strFirstName;
        return this;
    }

    public User withLastName(strLastName) {
        this.lastName = strLastName;
        return this;
    }


    //some other stuff
}
```

Then I initiate object with:

```
User testUser1 = new User()
                           .withFirstName("John")
                           .withLastName("Doe");
```

and then I do with it, what I need.

*P.S. Sorry for code not being python syntax... but you should get it*