# Removing the work from __init__ to aid unit testing

Tags: python, object-initializers

The key to this question is aiding unit-testing. If I have a busy `__init__` (i.e. `__init__` that does complex initialization), I cannot simply instantiate an object of a class, but I need to mock/stub out all methods invoked on dependencies within the `__init__`.

To illustrate this problem, here is example:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, dep1, dep2, some_string):
        self._dep1 = dep1
        self._dep2 = dep2
        self._some_string = some_string

        # I would need to mock everything here (imagine some even more
        # complicated example)
        for dep2element in self._dep2:
            dep2element.set_dep(dep1)
        self._dep1.set_some_string(some_string)

    def fun1(self):
        ...
    def fun2(self):
        ...
    def fun3(self):
        ...
```

To test the `fun*` functions, every test must perform the complex construction.

```
class TestSomeClass(TestCase):
    def create_SomeClass(self, some_string):
        dep1 = Mock()
        # mock everything required by SomeClass' constructor

        dep2 = Mock()
        # mock everything required by SomeClass' constructor

        return SomeClass(dep1, dep2, some_string)

    def test_fun1(self):
        sc = self.create_SomeClass('some string')
        ...

    def test_fun2(self):
        sc = self.create_SomeClass('some other string')
        ...

    def test_fun3(self):
        sc = self.create_SomeClass('yet another string')
        ...
```

I find this redundant and would like to know how this problems can be elegantly handled in python, if not by moving the work from the constructor.

**SOLUTION:**

As @ecatmur suggested, to test some specific function, this code should do the trick:

```
def test_some_method():
    mobject = Mock(SomeClass)
    SomeClass.fun1(mobject)
```

With this approach all the methods will be mocked out. If `fun1` calls some other method you want executed (e.g. `fun2`) you can do it like this:

```
def test_some_method():
    mobject = Mock(SomeClass)
    mobject.fun2 = SomeClass.fun2.__get__(mobject)
    SomeClass.fun1(mobject)
```

`SomeClass.fun2.__get__(mobject)` will produce `instancemethod` which will provide the correct binding.

**¡Viva el Python!**

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

Original question was centered around moving the work done in `__init__` to the separate `init` method and different problems revolving that approach. My usual approach is to make this

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, dep1, dep2, some_string)
        self._dep1 = dep1
        self._dep2 = dep2

        # lots of mumbo-jumbo here...
```

become this

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, dep1, dep2)
        self._dep1 = dep1
        self._dep2 = dep2

    def initiate(self, some-string)
        # lots of mumto-jumbo here...
```

General sentiment was that moving work from `__init__` is not a common practice and would be meaningless to seasoned python developers.

Comment: For starters, returning anything from init except None will raise an exception. But it's ok- you can still do your one line initialization. Init doesn't return anything, but the constructor still does.

Comment: A minor semantic point - in Python, the `__init__()` method isn't quite a "constructor". `__new__()` and `__init__()` share the function of a usual constructor. Whenever you do `a = MyClass()`, `MyClass.__new__()` is called, which creates and returns the object instance, on which `__init__()` is called, before returning the instance to be assigned to `a` (in this case).

Comment: I guess the exact wording would be 'constructor expression', but I already fixed that in my question...

Comment: **This** question made me understand why `def method(self):` is good in python ! **¡Viva el Python!** :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you write initialization functions separate from `__init__` then experienced developers will *certainly* see your code as a kid's playground.

If you're concerned about being able to create objects that look like instances of your class without running the `__init__` method, then use [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/):

```
def test_some_method():
    mock_object = Mock(MyClass)
    MyClass.some_method(mock_object)
```

Comment: The problem is the other way around: when I need to mock dependencies that SomeClass depends on. I expanded my post. Please, check it out. Thnx

Comment: @Vedran I don't understand; a half-constructed object isn't any use, so why would having one help with testing? You'd better post an example of an actual test you want to run on your class.

Comment: I rephrased my question entirely and hope the question is more to the point now.

Comment: @Vedran your question still doesn't make any sense; if your tests require a fully constructed `SomeClass` object then you need to run the constructor in full anyway; if they don't then a `Mock` object will do.

Comment: This is about testing `SomeClass` itself, and not about using SomeClass object to test something else. The point here is to restrict testing to only single unit of code (like functions `fun1`, `fun2` and `fun3`) in isolation from the other functions in a class or beyond. This comes down to removing all unnecessary code out of the requirements of a single unit test. In my example, this would mean that `fun1`, `fun2`, or `fun3` don't require full initialization, thus making the initialization code redundant from the perspective of a single unit test.

Comment: @Vedran so pass `Mock(SomeClass)` to `fun1` etc.

Comment: If I'm testing a function `fun1` which calls function `fun2`, both of which don't require the complex initialization, can I somehow install the `fun2` on the mock? Something like this: `mock.fun2 = MyClass.fun2`?

Comment: @Vedran almost, you have to write `mock.fun2 = MyClass.fun2.__get__(mock)`, to get the binding working right.

Comment: This will actually produce an instancemethod object? Kewl... Thnx for your help.

Answer (score 5):

`__init__` can't actually return anything; if you think about how it is used, this should be obvious:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        return ANYTHING

e = Example(1)   # how are you going to get ANYTHING back?
```

Using an `initialize()` method, separate from `__init__`, seems kind of silly - the whole point is that your initializer should automatically run when the object is created, so your example initialization should look like

```
scobj = SomeClass(dep1, dep2, 'abcdef')
# scobj.initialize('abcdef')     # <= separate call not needed!
```

**Edit:**

If you really need to factor the code in `__init__`, I suggest putting it in private methods and calling those from `__init__`, like so:

```
class Example2(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self._init_connection(a)
        self._init_display(b)
        self.c = c

    def _init_connection(self, a):
        self.conn = make_connection(a)

    def _init_display(self, b):
        self.disp = make_display(b)
```

... this is good because

- all initialization is done on creating the object (you don't need to remember to make follow-up initialization calls)
- you don't have to keep a flag to remember whether your object has been initialized or not - if it exists, it has been initialized.

Comment: I'll expand my intro to the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Klass:
    def __init__(self):
        initialize instance here, no return
```

`__init__` will automatically run at object creation, so you don't need to check if it run; it **was** run if you have an instance!

About returning self from init(): I wouldn't, as it is an in-place operation. Read the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682567/why-does-pythons-list-append-evaluate-to-false), as it explains this pretty well.

Comment: I already know about the __init__, so I'll just expand my examples. Thnx for the answer,

Comment: Then use it? what's the problem about `__init__`?

Comment: The problem with constructor is that i don't want to have too much work in it. The key is here is to aid unit testing, and I don't want to have to mock everything that might be needed in the busy constructor.

Comment: You need to put it somewhere, what's the problem with putting it in `__init__`?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, dep1, dep2, st=None):
        self._dep1 = dep1
        self._dep2 = dep2
        if st is None:
            self._initialized = False
        else:
            self.initialize(st)

    def initialize(self, st):
        ...
        self._initialized = True
        ...
```

?

Comment: Why not putting self._initialized away?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with splitting `__init__()` out into separate methods. If you can do it in a way which makes those methods appropriately named and reusable, then all the better - e.g.:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, dep1, dep2, some_string):
        self.set_dependencies(dep1, dep2, some_string)

    def set_dependencies(self, dep1, dep2, some_string):
        self._dep1 = dep1
        self._dep2 = dep2
        self._some_string = some_string

        for dep2element in self._dep2:
            dep2element.set_dep(dep1)
        self._dep1.set_some_string(some_string)
```

Here, a `remove_dependencies()` method could be added in the future to revert the instance to a neutral state, before setting new dependencies. The functionality is decoupled from the initialisation process.

Note I've called this from `__init__()`, even though we don't want this to run in testing. If we *don't* call this from `__init__()`, someone using this class would have to call `set_dependencies()` after instantiating - which is an unnecessary complication to your class's API.

What we can do is stub the method out for testing, e.g.:

```
class TestSomeClass(TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
        SomeClass._old_set_dependencies = SomeClass.set_dependencies
        SomeClass.set_dependencies = lambda *args: None

    ...
```

This is a pretty brash way of stubbing out a method, just to prove a point really - there are some good libraries out there for doing it more diligently - see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98053/what-is-your-favorite-python-mocking-library), but I'd also recommend [Mockstar](http://mockstar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) which is an extension to [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html) designed to simplify the semantics.

Comment: This is great. :) Can you name some of those libraries? I guess that mock.patch would work, but I guess there are other solutions too.

Comment: I've added some relevant links to my answer.