# Programming a web API with test driven development

Tags: python, mocking, tdd

I'm creating a web API in Python which communicates with some other web API's (Facebook, twitter, etc) en a other web API which is programmed at the same time as my API.

Since I like to use test driven development, I wonder how I can apply TDD to my web API. I know about mocking but how can I mock other API's and how can I mock calls to my  API.

Update 1: To specify my question.  Is it possible to create a web API with TDD under the conditions specified above. If yes, is there a library I can use in Python to do so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but I think your question is too vague and overly broad to be answered here on SO; see the [FAQ#dontask]. If you have more concrete problems (preferably involving some code), feel free to ask those!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your question is rather broad, I'll just refer you:

- for mocking in python there is a library called [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/), documentation is pretty detailed
- [Python Unit Testing with Mock](http://www.insomnihack.com/?p=194)
- [What is your favorite Python mocking library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98053/what-is-your-favorite-python-mocking-library)

Here's a simple example of using mock to mock [python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter)'s `GetSearch` method:

- `test_module.py`

  ```
  import twitter


  def get_tweets(hashtag):
      api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key',
                        consumer_secret='consumer_secret',
                        access_token_key='access_token',
                        access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
      api.VerifyCredentials()
      results = api.GetSearch(hashtag)
      return results
  ```
- `test_my_module.py`

  ```
  from unittest import TestCase
  from mock import patch
  import twitter
  from my_module import get_tweets


  class MyTestCase(TestCase):
      def test_ok(self):
          with patch.object(twitter.Api, 'GetSearch') as search_method:
              search_method.return_value = [{'tweet1', 'tweet2'}]

              self.assertEqual(get_tweets('blabla'), [{'tweet1', 'tweet2'}])
  ```

You probably should mock the whole `Api` object in your unittests in order to still call them `unit tests`.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you i can figure it out from here.